# How are these GHC options getting into my stack build?

Tags: ghc, haskell-stack

I'm seeing the following, at the end of a "stack build foo":

> Progress: 1/2
>   --  While building package foo-0.1.0.0 using:
>         [path-to-GHC] --builddir=[path-to-stack-work-area] build lib:foo
>   --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
>       Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1

And I can't figure out how those options: **-ddump-hi** and **-ddump-to-file**, are getting into my stack build flow. I can't find them in:

- stack.yaml,
- foo.cabal, or
- foo.hs

Does anyone know where they're coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're added by stack, the reason for it is so that stack can know about Template Haskell file dependencies, and so can know when recompilation is needed.